# TPIL 4.4: example : ¬ (∀ x, ¬ p x) → (∃ x, p x)

Tags: lean

Section 4.4 of Theorem Proving in Lean shows the following:

```
(∃ x, p x) ↔ ¬ (∀ x, ¬ p x) := sorry
```

Here I'll focus on the right-to-left case:

```
¬ (∀ x, ¬ p x) → (∃ x, p x)
```

We know we'll have a parameter of type `¬ (∀ x, ¬ p x)` so let's start with that:

```
example : ¬ (∀ x, ¬ p x) → (∃ x, p x) := 
    (assume hnAxnpx : ¬ (∀ x, ¬ p x),
        _ 
    )
```

At this point, if we try to use `exists.intro` with `x`:

```
example : ¬ (∀ x, ¬ p x) → (∃ x, p x) := 
    (assume hnAxnpx : ¬ (∀ x, ¬ p x),
        exists.intro x _)
```

we'll get an error because `x` is an unknown identifier.

However, as part of this set of exercises, we are given:

```
variables a : α
```

so let's try to use `exists.intro` with that:

```
example : ¬ (∀ x, ¬ p x) → (∃ x, p x) := 
    (assume hnAxnpx : ¬ (∀ x, ¬ p x),
        exists.intro a _)
```

We don't have a `p a` so let's try to use classical logic via `em`:

The first clause of `or.elim` is handled in a straightforward manner:

```
example : ¬ (∀ x, ¬ p x) → (∃ x, p x) := 
    (assume hnAxnpx : ¬ (∀ x, ¬ p x),
        or.elim (em (p a))
            (λ hpa : p a, exists.intro a hpa)
            (λ hnpa : ¬ p a, _))
```

Since we have a function which goes from `(∀ x, ¬ p x)` to `false` (i.e. `hnAxnpx`), let's try to build a value of type `(∀ x, ¬ p x)`. Then we can call `hnAxnpx` on it and use `false.elim`.

```
example : ¬ (∀ x, ¬ p x) → (∃ x, p x) := 
    (assume hnAxnpx : ¬ (∀ x, ¬ p x),    
        or.elim (em (p a))        
            (λ hpa : p a, exists.intro a hpa)    
            (λ hnpa : ¬ p a, false.elim (hnAxnpx (λ a, _))))
```

At this point it seems we're so close! we're told we need a `¬p a` where the underscore is. And it seems that `hnpa` is just such a value. So let's try that:

```
example : ¬ (∀ x, ¬ p x) → (∃ x, p x) :=     
    (assume hnAxnpx : ¬ (∀ x, ¬ p x),    
        or.elim (em (p a))        
            (λ hpa : p a, exists.intro a hpa)    
            (λ hnpa : ¬ p a, false.elim (hnAxnpx (λ a, hnpa))))
```

However, with that we get the following error:

```
type mismatch at application
  hnAxnpx (λ (a : α), hnpa)
term
  λ (a : α), hnpa
has type
  α → ¬p a
but is expected to have type
  ∀ (x : α), ¬p x
```

Should I continue with the approach illustrated above? Or should an entirely different approach be considered?

---

**UPDATE**

Here's another approach:

```
example : ¬ (∀ x, ¬ p x) → (∃ x, p x) := 
    (assume hnAxnpx : ¬ (∀ x, ¬ p x),
        false.elim (hnAxnpx
            (λ x,
                (λ hpx : p x, _)))) -- Here we'll need a false.
```

However, at that point, it isn't clear to me how to get a `false` value at the point of the underscore.

**UPDATE**

Mario Carneiro on the leanprover zulip group [provided the following very helpful hints](https://leanprover.zulipchat.com/#narrow/stream/113489-new-members/topic/example.20.3A.20.C2.AC.20%28.E2.88.80.20x.2C.20.C2.AC.20p.20x%29.20.E2.86.92.20%28.E2.88.83.20x.2C.20p.20x%29/near/179817744) in regards to this last approach:

> Don't use `false.elim` where you did; that's throwing away the
>   information that we are trying to prove `(∃ x, p x)` and leads to an
>   unsolvable state
>
> Use by_contradiction there instead, which gives you additionally the
>   assumption that `¬ (∃ x, p x)`

Going with this advice we get:

```
example : ¬ (∀ x, ¬ p x) → (∃ x, p x) := 
    (assume hnAxnpx : ¬ (∀ x, ¬ p x),
        by_contradiction
            (λ hnExpx : ¬ (∃ x, p x), 
                (hnAxnpx
                    (λ x, (λ hpx, 
                        hnExpx (exists.intro x hpx))))))
```

which appears to work.

Comment: `term
  λ (a : α), hnpa
has type
  α → ¬p a`. Are you using `a` twice and getting confused?

Comment: @KevinBuzzard Well, it was suggested to me on zulipchat that I not use the global `a` at all. :-) So now I'm considering how to get at the `x`.